# jQuery Tools – Image change on hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function() {
  return typeof o!=="undefined"&&
            !o.event.triggered 
               ? o.event.handle.apply(arguments.callee.elem,arguments)
               : g
}
```

I'm working on an asp.net site. For product categories on the website, the images for the categories are fed from a database. I've got those going fine, but the image for mouseover event is from some other part of the site. The site is using a library I've never heard of called jQuery tools with something called a sizzler css engine. If it helps, here is a link to the page I'm working on. You will notice the Duck Commander link can't change to a hover image.

The code above is what developer tools found was activating to change the image.

[The Website in Question](http://fireworkssupermarket.com/Product)

Comment: Just a thought, but as an intern, shouldn't you be being taught by the people around you?  Ask questions, that's why you're there!

Comment: Have you looked online at the documentation?

Comment: Have you seen http://jquerytools.github.io/download/?

Comment: There is not a single person here that knows programming aside from me. Odd internship, but it's interesting. There really isn't much documentation on their website.

Comment: @ScottKnox You should consider changing your internship workplace.

Comment: Their site doesn't even work anymore. You can't download any of the code or really use anything.

Comment: jQuery should never be used for this situation. Research CSS sprites or even SVG

Comment: Does `duckCommander_over.png` exist?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the Duck Commander mouse over image:

`GET http://fireworkssupermarket.com/Content/images/categories/duckCommander_over.png 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1):

While I don't necessarily agree with the design of the site, I can understand coming in to a project that you can't start from scratch on.

That said, it appears to me that you are simply missing the hover image file titled "duckCommander_over.png" at path:

```
Content/images/categories
```

Find this folder in your file structure and see if the file exists, if it doesn't, you'll need to create it.

Comment: Looks like zgood beat me to it! He should take the rep.

Answer (score 1):

Scott,

You're simply missing the image file needed for the hover action to retrieve. The site is looking for a 'duckCommander_over.png' file which is non-existent on your site. Looks like the hover images were manually created in an image program (it's not an effect applied through CSS or JavaScript) so you'll have to upload an image with the red glow already applied and name it 'duckCommander_over.png'